# Scroll to bottom of RecyclerView from Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know there is a way to scroll to the bottom of a RecyclerView from Activities, but is there any way I can scroll to the bottom of a RecyclerView from the Adapter? I want to scroll to the bottom when an EditText is focused upon.

Here is some of my Adapter where I would like to scroll to the bottom of the RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    final int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

    updatePrefs();

    holder.editTextListener.updatePosition(position);
    holder.studentText.setHint(mDataset.get(position));
    holder.studentNumber.setText(position + 1 + ".");

    if (position != 0) {
        holder.studentText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    holder.studentText.setHint(v.getContext().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.prompt_student_name));
                    setDeleteListener(holder.studentDelete, position);
                    holder.studentText.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);

                    mDataset.add(v.getContext().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.prompt_new_student_name));
                    notifyItemInserted(position + 1);

                    //SCROLL TO BOTTOM OF RECYCLERVIEW
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Check to make sure they're not deleting their only way of adding a new EditText
    if (!holder.studentText.getHint().equals(holder.studentText.getContext().getResources()
            .getString(R.string.prompt_new_student_name))) {
        setDeleteListener(holder.studentDelete, position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing the context to the adapter and then using `((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)` and scroll method over it didn't work?

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I added it as an answer, hoping it will also give more visibility

Answer (score 1):

First you get a reference of the `Context` inside your layout, most simple way is to pass it through the constructor:

```
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> data, Context context) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context= context;
}
```

Inside your callback, just get the reference to the `RecyclerView` from the `Context` you passed before

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        ...
        RecyclerView recyclerView = ((Activity) this.context).findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        ... use RecyclerView for your purpose  
    }
}
```

Actually you could have fetch the reference directly of the `RecyclerView` out of your adapter and then passing the `RecyclerView` reference instead of the `Context`. I don't see any difference, but usually I use the above method since I may need to update other UI elements and it's more handy to do in this way.

Comment: Most of the time you can get a 'fresher' `Context` from within your method by doing:
`holder.itemView.getContext()`
So you avoid troubles when using your `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: You forgot to parse returned view from findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) to RecyclerView. It should done like this RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) ((Activity) this.context).findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);